# How can I remove stinky radiator water from a rug?

Tags: cleaning

While I was away I had a radiator leak in my apartment, to the point water was leaking into the apartment downstairs.

My rug absorbed most of it, and absolutely stinks. What would be the best way to clean out the rug, or is it beyond saving?

I live in NYC, so I don't have the option of a backyard or balcony to dry it out...

Comment: what's your rug replacement cost? if it's less than $50 or $100 (depending on your personal tolerance levels), you may be better served dumping it and getting a new one. specially with no place to dry it out in the open...

Comment: @alt It was right about $50...was hoping I could save it instead of heaving to just replace it, it seems like such a waste...it's dry at the moment, just not clean.

Answer (score 3):

Replacement makes the most sense here. You can fuss with steam-cleaning it, but you may not get all the smell out and the cost may exceed the cost of a new rug, per comments above. Toss it, clean the floor well, and replace if desired.